# How to open pdf in new blank pop up window and download

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to reproduce a scenario for debugging some issue for which I need to click on date which opens a new pop up window which is blank and pdf gets downloaded in that window. So far I am only able to download pdf in same window it does not open in new window and then download.

HTML code tried:-

```
<a href="javascript:open('C://Users//abcd//Desktop//freeformatter-decoded.pdf','mypopuptitle','width=600,height=400')"  id="1" style="cursor: pointer; color: rgb(14, 87, 193); text-decoration: none;">First acc</a>

<a target="_blank" href="C://Users//abcd//Desktop//freeformatter-decoded.pdf">First acc</a>
```

Below screenshot shows the scenario which I want to recreate:-

[image]

On click on 04/05/2018 a pdf should get downloaded in new pop up window. Note that pop window is blank it just downloads pdf. Please help in writing html/javascript for above. I need to recreate exact use case.

Answer (score 1):

`<a target="_blank" href="C://Users//abcd//Desktop//freeformatter-decoded.pdf" download>First acc</a>` using `download` attribute you can download

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to open pdf url in another window-

```
window.open("url/sample.pdf", "_blank");
```